# How to make web database that will collect data from sharepoint calendar in real time?

Tags: calendar, database, access

I want to make database out of data users' input in project calendar. Basically every user types in working hours in project calendar (how many hours each day they had worked on that specific project) and I would like to get that data in web database and be able to make bills and other reports from it.

Also I would like that web base is available in real time, not just import data into database once. The data should be visible always.

**TLDR**: How to link data from sharepoint calendar into web database in real 
time?

**Note**: Web database I want to import those data in is access web base

Comment: EDIT: Web database I want to import those data in is access web base

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion. A SharePoint Calendar can be linked to an Access Database trough the Data Connections to SharePoint Lists. I tested and it worked. If you want the Access Database to be a Web Database, just make it a Web Access Database.